# Lodash way of creating a custom function

Tags: lodash, currying

I'm trying to implement a simple function in pure lodash way.

```
function forward(i) => {
  return (j) => {
    return String.fromCharCode(i + j)
  }
}
```

So that I can do `_.range(26).map(forward(65))`. Take me some time to make this work:

```
function a = _.wrap(String.fromCharCode, (fn, a, b) => fn(a + b))
function b = _.ary(a, 2)
function forward = _.curry(b)
```

Now my question is is there an easier way to do this? and how do I use `sum` to construct `(fn, a, b) => fn(a + b)`?

One last thing is I couldn't find wrap function file in Lodash repo.

Comment: Is `const forward = _.curry(_.flow([_.add, String.fromCharCode]), 2)` that suits your requirements?

Comment: @Caramiriel - you should convert this to an answer. btw - you don't have to use the brackets inside flow - `_.curry(_.flow(_.add, String.fromCharCode), 2)`

Comment: Yes!, this should be accepted answer.

Comment: Added an answer; I was just waiting to see if it was within what Mengo expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `_.curry(...)` is kind of strange when it comes to calling functions with various parameters. Let me guide you with an example below.

The ary-function (`_.ary(..., 2)`) takes any function and ensures its never called with more than a specific amount of arguments (in this case two). Less arguments than specified, will just end up calling the underlying function with less arguments. A definition of this function could look like this:

```
function ary() {
    const args = arguments;

    // implementation
}
```

There is no way to tell how many arguments the function is expecting, as you would with a function with actual parameters (`function(a, b) { }`). If you would define `const forward1 = _.curry(_.ary(target, 2))`, and call it with `forward1(42)(2)`, the curry function would just pass down the first argument to `ary` as it thinks its done.

We can get around this by using an overload of `curry` that specifies how many parameters the underlying function is expecting (`const forward2 = _.curry(target, 2)`). Only in the case where `forward2` is called in a curry-style (not sure what its even called) with two parameters, it passes it down to `target`. A call with one argument will just return a new function, waiting for it to be called with the second argument. Now we can get rid of the `ary`-call, as it serves us no purpose anymore.

---

As for chaining actions, there's a helper for that. For example: `c(b(a(...)` can be rewritten to `_.flow([a, b, c])`. Lodash also provides a function for `a + b`, which is `_.add()`.

---

Together your problem can be rewritten to:

```
const forward = _.curry(_.flow([_.add, String.fromCharCode]), 2);
```

or more verbose:

```
const methods = _.flow([
    _.add,
    String.fromCharCode
]);

const forward = _.curry(methods, 2);
```

Note that the `2` corresponds to the amount of parameters the `_.add` method expects.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! After a second thought, I'm thinking `_.range(26).map(add(65)).map(String.fromCharCode)` is easier to understand. But it's quit interesting to know the use of `flow` and `curry` has an optional arity argument!

Comment: Can you also help me on finding `wrap` function file in lodash repo? I have an idea of how it it implemented, but I couldn't find the source code.

Comment: No, not `flow`. I'm looking for `wrap` function. :D @Caramiriel

Comment: Excuse me, I didnt read well enough: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L10934 - Theres a button "source" under the function on the documentation page: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#wrap

Comment: Good to know! Thank you!